# How to unconcat pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to use some function that requires to concat two dataframe. Here is the example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data1 = np.array([['','Col1','Col2'],['1',1,2],['2',3,4]])
data1=pd.DataFrame(data=data1[1:,1:],index=data1[1:,0],columns=data1[0,1:])
data2=np.array([['','Col1','Col2'],['1',5,6],['2',7,8]])
data2=pd.DataFrame(data=data2[1:,1:],index=data2[1:,0],columns=data2[0,1:])
X=pd.concat([data1,data2],0)
X_transformed=func(X)
```

Now I want to unconcat X_transformed back into the original data1 and data2. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add parameter `keys` to [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) for distinguish each DataFrame and then select by `loc`:

```
X=pd.concat([data1,data2],0, keys=[0,1])
print (X)
    Col1 Col2
0 1    1    2
  2    3    4
1 1    5    6
  2    7    8

data11 = X.loc[0]
data22 = X.loc[1]
print (data11)
  Col1 Col2
1    1    2
2    3    4

print (data22)
  Col1 Col2
1    5    6
2    7    8
```

EDIT:

More general solution:

```
data3=data2.iloc[[0]].rename({'1':'10'})

dfs = [data1,data2,data3]
X=pd.concat(dfs, keys=np.arange(len(dfs)))
print (X)
     Col1 Col2
0 1     1    2
  2     3    4
1 1     5    6
  2     7    8
2 10    5    6

print (X.xs(0))
  Col1 Col2
1    1    2
2    3    4

print (X.xs(1))
  Col1 Col2
1    5    6
2    7    8

print (X.xs(2))
   Col1 Col2
10    5    6
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your way but X_transformed return more columns than X. So X (which has 2row 2col) changed to X_transformed (which has 2row, 4col). In this case, using .loc doesn't return dataframe but instead returning series.

Comment: @Lemma - What about `X.loc[[0]]` ? Or `X.xs(0)` ?

Comment: The expected output is 2row and 4 col. X.loc[[0]] return dataframe which has 1row and 4 col. X.xs(0) return series: (2,)

Comment: @Lemma - First, do you add parameter `keys` to `concat` ?

Comment: Yes, I added keys

Comment: EDITED: I tried using X_transformed.loc[[0]] rather than using X

Comment: @Lemma - What return `X_transformed` ? Not sure if understand.

Comment: X_transformed=func(X)...this return 2row and 4col. The original X is only 2row and 2col, like in the example above

Comment: @Lemma - So what is `X_transformed` from sample data? Are columns names changed? Are index values changed?

Comment: Ok sorry it seems that I use .reset_index(drop=True) during concating. Now your solution works after that. THANKS!!

Comment: @Lemma - I hope so, because `.reset_index(drop=True)` reset index to original `0,1,2...N`. If some problem, let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`X_transformed.iloc[:data1.shape[0]]` is the first dataframe. `X_transformed.iloc[data1.shape[0]:]` is the second one.

Comment: Hi. Thanks but what if there's the third dataframe? Using X_transformed.iloc[data3.shape[0]:] will return the second dataframe instead of the third one right?